# Send more params with rails form_for or POST another way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a form_for in Rails, and also send an extra parameter with the POST request.

I have an Agency class which has many Alerts. The Alert class belongs_to an Agency. So, if I have an instance of Alert stored in @alert, I should be able to say @alert.agency.

Thereore, in the Alert.create method, I should be able to redirect_to @alert.agency. But, I haven't passed the agency_id to the create method in the first place. I want to, but I'm not sure how.

---

**Alert.rb**

```
class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
end
```

**Agency.rb**

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account, as: :member, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :alerts
end
```

**AlertController.rb**

```
class AlertController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_alert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @alert = Alert.new
  end

  def create
    @alert = Alert.new(body: params[:body], severity: params[:severity])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @alert.save
        format.html { redirect_to @alert.agency, notice: 'Alert created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @alert}
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_alert
      @alert = Alert.find(params[:id])
    end

    def alert_params
      params.require(:alert).permit(:body, :severity, :agency_id)
    end
end
```

---

I have made a partial named _create_alert which I placed with the Agencies views. I render it in show.html.erb. Here is it:

**_create_post.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(alert_create_url) do %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div>
        <%= text_area_tag :body, params[:body], placeholder: 'Type alert here' %> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= number_field_tag :severity, params[:severity], placeholder: 'Type alert here' %> 
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= submit_tag "Post", class: 'btn linky' %>
      </div> 
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I placed this partial in views/Agencies/ because I felt that it was more natural to place it there. I didn't see an advantage to it being in views/Alerts/.

Now the problem comes up because I don't pass in the agency's ID with the form_for. How can I send this information as well?
I do have it stored in the session, so I could just access it from the session within Alert.create, but I feel like that is unsafe and not the best practice.

---

**I think I have two options:**

**1.** Pass the agency ID with the other parameters using form_for

**2.** From the Agency.show view, when the user hits submit I can grab their text from the HTML elements and pass that with @agency.alerts.create()

Is there another option? Which of the above methods would be preferred?
How can I implement either of the above options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "parameter_name", session[:agency_id] %>
```

in your `form_for`.

Then in you can get it in your controller like this

```
params[:parameter_name]
```

Comment: This feels dirty. Should I have that logic in a view?

Comment: You state that you want to send it as parameter, there's no way that you can send a parameter unless you put it inside your form using input tag. As you stated, you can also directly access your agency id on your controller since it is stored in a session

Comment: Well I wasn't sure how to word it. I want to have access to it in the Alert.create method. If I didn't have it stored in session, is there a better way to organize my code to have access to it?

Comment: Also, using hidden_field_tag, can the user modify the information with a browser plug-in?

Comment: then just call the session on your controller, so that it will not appear on the page even you inspect element the page or whatever plugin you are using, unless you will try to change the value of the session